# Unity - Fade Out Stencil Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I'm developing a menu system and, right now, I'm making heavy use of CanvasGroups to handle the fading in/out of my menu. I really want to use a new stencil mask shader for certain parts of the menu which I have done and it works, I now have this nice portal-like effect going on when I look through the stencil. The problem I have is that I can't control the fading in of my stencil objects like I do with my CanvasGroups. I've tried adding extra properties to my stencil shader to handle the Alpha from the frag() function but this doesn't appear to have helped. Note that my shader using a Geometry Render Queue.

Here's my Shader:

```
Shader "Stencils/StencilMask" {
    Properties {
        [IntRange] _StencilMask("Stencil Mask", Range(0, 255)) = 0
        _Fade("Fade", Range(0,1)) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
        }

        ColorMask 0
        ZWrite off
        Stencil {
            Ref[_StencilMask]
            Comp always
            Pass replace
        }

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            // Upgrade NOTE: excluded shader from DX11; has structs without semantics (struct appdata members vertColor)
            #pragma exclude_renderers d3d11 fade:alpha
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            float _Fade;

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 position : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
                return fixed4(1,1,0,_Fade);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```